# Is it possible to have a SQL Server database with case sensitive data only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case-sensitive

Is it possible to have a SQL Server 2012 database with a collation that ensures only the data is treated as case sensitive, with the database objects still referenced in a case insensitive manner?

We are migrating the database used by an application to SQL Server, and this database contains case sensitive data. But we don't want the database objects to be treated in a case sensitive manner, as that will have a significant negative impact on the existing code.

All research tends to suggest that this isn't possible, and the best we can do is identify which columns really do need to be case sensitive, and set the collation for these accordingly so we can minimize the damage. Is this the best we can hope for?

Comment: I'd recommend using a case-insensitive database collation, and then defining individual columns, as necessary, as case-sensitive. Another option, if it makes sense in your context is to use varbinary data types to represent strings.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like having individual column collation may be the best route. We need to minimize the changes required to application code as much as possible, and I think that will probably be the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cleggy, it looks like you already got the answer from @Xedni's comment, but adding it here as a reference for anyone reading this page in future.

SQL Server collation settings depend on the type of installation. Case sensitivity is subject to collation of the data.

By default, databases created with SQL Server inherit the server collation. 
By default, column in tables created in a database inherit the database collation.

There are plenty of opportunities to choose a case sensitive collation for your data between these options:

> 1. By choosing one when you create the database (Or)
> 2. By choosing one when you design the table

Please follow this link for more on [SQL Server Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260(v=sql.105).aspx).

We can change the database collation to case sensitive using the following T-SQL.

```
ALTER DATABASE <Database_Name> COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

The following T-SQL will be helpful in understanding the various case sensitivity options.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_helpcollations()
```